# What is the use case for textedit in 2023?

Tags: text-editor, textedit

I think the main usage of textedit is to edit [RTF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) as that is the default format textedit uses to save files. But even Microsoft doesn't seem to use RTF format anymore, ["Microsoft has discontinued enhancements to the RTF specification"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and as "In a 2020 insider build of Windows 10, [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) is modified to include advertising notifications for the Office web apps as an alternative."

I think one use case for RTF file is for **cross-platform sharing**, but we have other file formats for that (pdf, md). BTW, I always find the name "**R**ich **T**ext **F**ormat" is a bit misleading. Any text editors online now have some kind of so-called **Rich Text** Format support, e.g. as I am writing this question here, but they are NOT the rtf format we were talking about when using textedit (or WordPad on Windows).

So what is use case for TextEdit in 2023?

Comment: “I think the main usage of textedit is to edit RTF file” — [citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)…

Comment: @gidds then what is your opinion ? Why does textedit use RTF as its default format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a basic requirement for an operating system to have an app which will edit plain text files. TextEdit is that app in macOS. There are alternatives (e.g. BBEdit), but TextEdit is the app included by Apple.

I would suggest that editing RTF and RTFD is a lesser requirement. But again any operating system needs to have an editor for them if only for historical reasons. And for macOS it is the common format for basic documents with some formatting, fonts, etc.

I would be appalled if the only way to edit a file was to do it on-line.

You examples of other formats:

MD: Apart from not having an agreed standard, it is only a minority who use markdown and anyway it is built on plain text files. So, the basic editor for markdown is TextEdit.

PDF: Most people don't need a PDF creator/editor. Apple supply an app (Preview) to annotate PDF documents.

Comment: I would be doubly appalled if Apple suggested using web apps just to open an RTF file.

Comment: macOS does have a pdf creator - The print dialog allows you to print to pdf. But this is not a good comparison pdfs are not editable, you have to edit another format and then generate a pdf/

Comment: @benwiggy I always think the name RTF is misleading. As I said in my question, any online text editor can let you write a "rich format" text but they are NOT rtf format we were talking about here.

Comment: Although I accepted your answer but I am not satisfied with your words "I would be appalled if the only way to edit a file was to do it on-line." What was NOT my intention when I said  "Any text editors online now have some kind of so-called Rich Text Format support". I was to emphasize that I thought the name "rtf" is misleading.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 I was treating your question as primarily about TextEdit (as in the title) with RTF files as the only use you could see for TextEdit.  But I do think you are being a bit hard on the Rich Text Format which was created in 1987 and is still in use.